# Best solution for flying with a big dog?

Tags: air-travel, sweden, pets

Living in Sweden, but with family in The Netherlands and Finland, we (me & my partner) will be traveling much back and forth. We have done this so far by planes.

We are both crazy about dogs and would like to get one soon. We have read that dogs over 8kg can't be in the cabin but go in the luggage/storage part. To me this sounds rather horrible for a dog (even if the temperature is the same).

What are your experiences with flying with a dog. Specially when you have a medium/big dog I wonder how people solve it. Do you take the dog in the plane or do you leave it home? Don't dogs get a trauma from flying? Is going by car/train/bus better?

Comment: You're probably going to find http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/788/101 very useful...

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to leave it at a dog hotel, if you only travel for a few days? I know for a fact that such facilities are available in Sweden. and while not cheap, the cost could be worthwhile.

Comment: After reading rlesko's links I think your suggestion is quite a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out foXnoMad's blog post about it [here](http://foxnomad.com/2010/09/23/the-ultimate-guide-to-traveling-internationally-with-your-pets-part-1/) and [here](http://foxnomad.com/2010/09/24/the-ultimate-guide-to-traveling-internationally-with-your-pets-part-2/). It's a two part topic and I would quote it here but there's too much so check it out at his blog. The links probably won't die since it's a quite popular blog.