# Traveling from USA to Germany with a German Shepherd

Tags: air-travel, usa, transportation, germany, pets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I travel to Germany with my dog?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-can-i-travel-to-germany-with-my-dog)

What do I need to get/do for my German Shepherd to be able to take him to Germany?

Comment: Dupe of "[How can I travel to Germany with my dog?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/788/349)"

Answer (score 2):

According to the [EU Regulation (EC) no 998/2003](http://ec.europa.eu/food/animal/liveanimals/pets/index_en.htm) :

> To move a dog, cat or ferret as a pet animal under the conditions laid
>   down in Regulation (EC) no 998/2003, the owner must prove
>   that the animal meets the following criteria:
>
> ```
> (a) animal of one of the species listed in Annex I to Regulation (EC) no 998/2003;
>
> (b) the movement of the animal must be triggered by the need of the owner to move;
>
> (c) the animal must not be intended to be sold or transferred to another owner in the context of the regulated movement.
> ```

Comment: The link is useful, but the text you quote is a bit misleading.  Those are not the only requirements to move an animal!  Instead, they help to determine which other rules apply.  However, the linked page contains further links (under "Topics") which actually list the regulations.

Comment: Quoted regulation is definition of non-commercial moving of animal (as opposed to commercial one). Not sure how that's useful.

Answer (score 2):

There are no specific rules for Germany, general EU rules apply.

Your dog needs rabies vaccine and health certificate on [official EU form](http://ec.europa.eu/food/animal/liveanimals/pets/pet_import_certificates_en.doc) filled in by certified veterinarian no more than 10 days before travel.

Whole process described in details in [USA Today's "How to Travel With Pets to Europe"](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/travel-pets-europe-1600.html)