# How do I travel to the USA with my dog (from Europe)?

Tags: usa, international-travel, california, pets

I'm moving from Germany to California with my dog.  She's [originally from the USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-can-i-travel-to-germany-with-my-dog), but we've been in Germany for three years.

What do I need to do to travel back to the USA with my dog (10 lbs Chihuahua)?

She is microchipped, has a European pet passport, and is confirmed as an in-cabin pet on our flights (operated by Lufthansa).  We're flying into SFO.

What can I expect from US Customs?  Do I require any further documentation?

**References**

- "[Bringing a Dog into the United States](http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/dogs.html)" from the CDC

Answer (score 3):

You've found one link but basically you just didn't link others:

- [APHIS from US Department of Agriculture](http://www.aphis.usda.gov/wps/portal/aphis/ourfocus/importexport?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2Faphis_content_library%2Fsa_our_focus%2Fsa_animal_health%2Fsa_import_into_us%2Fsa_entry_requirements%2Fct_us%2Bstate_and_territory_animal_import_regulations)
- [State of California](http://www.cdfa.ca.gov//ahfss/Animal_Health/Entry_Requirements.html)
- [US Customs and Border Protection (Dogs)](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/55/~/pets---dogs,-rabies-vaccines)
- [US CBP (Pets in General)](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/66/~/pets-and-wildlife---general-information)

CDC also has information on what to expect when [traveling with pets](http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/travelingpets.html) as well as some information on [Foreign Born](http://www.foreignborn.com/visas_imm/entering_us/2bringyourpet.htm) and a few other sites.

Long story short the procedure for bringing pets through customs is fairly simple you present your pet and all the documentation pertaining to its health to a US Customs officer and your pet may be examined and if nothing is found then you just continue on your way.

Comment: I have a "European Pet Passport" - is that enough documentation?  It has sign-offs for rabies vaccine and "good health for travel."

Comment: @nibot As long as a US Customs official can read in English that your pet is Rabies and Screwworm free you should be fine.

Comment: Also, for anyone moving to Hawaii, the Aloha State imposes a [quarantine](http://hdoa.hawaii.gov/ai/aqs/animal-quarantine-information-page/) on dogs and cats.

Comment: @choster True but we're talking about California in this question.

Comment: @Karlson Yes, hence "Also, for anyone moving to Hawaii…." I thought I would mention it since the question title asks about the entire USA.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following things to prepare for my transatlantic journey with my little dog:

- Went to the vet.  My dog's rabies shot had recently expired, so she got a new one.  This was noted in my dog's "European Pet Passport" that we had gotten on an earlier vet visit.
- I phoned Lufthansa to add an in-cabin pet to my reservation.  (Later, at the airport I paid a 70 EUR fee for this.)

Upon arriving at San Francisco International Airport, there were no additional formalities. I went into the "I have stuff to declare" line at customs after the baggage claim and said I had a dog.  The inspectors didn't take one look at my dog. They did ask whether I had any *dog food* and asked to look at it -- after a glance at the bag, they declared that OK too.

So: the whole process was totally easy and painless.  It turns out that traveling between Europe and the U.S. with a small dog is not a very big deal.